# What happen to a pair of entangled photons when they enter a polarizing beam splitter?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
Suppose we have two entangled photons in the state of $(\ket{HH}+\ket{VV})/\sqrt{2}$ and one of them enters through the mode a of a polarizing beam splitter and the other one enters the mode b of the same polarizing beam splitter. What is the state after they exit? Does Hong-Ou-Mandel effect also apply here, if yes how? Thanks

Comment: In this case, for this state, nothing interesting happens. You get back the same state. HOM does not work here because a PBS does not split the photon.

Comment: do you know how to compute output states after a beamsplitter? In the standard HOM effect you'd use as input state $a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger|0\rangle$, meaning two indistinguishable photons enter each mode. You're considering as input state something written as $(a_{1,H}^\dagger a_{2,H}^\dagger + a_{1,V}^\dagger a_{2,V}^\dagger)|0\rangle$, but computing output states will proceed identically

Comment: $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
No, unfortunately.I am a computer science student, studying quantum networks. I am trying to calculate a density operator for a PBS. I read this https://copilot.caltech.edu/documents/16791/weihs_zeillinger_photon_statistics_at_beamsplitters_qip.pdf But, it is hard to implement it. I wonder how can I wright an entangled state and the state that includes two photons in the state $\ket{HH}+\ket{HV}+\ket{VH}+\ket{VV}$ each goes toward a mode. In the case of entangled state  the output is the same but for the second case we have entangled with 0.5 prob.

Comment: @gIS How can I compute output? I think I need a density operator.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want a *polarizing* beam splitter? And why do you care about the question in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to write down a density operator for the polarizing beam splitter. I am thinking about different situations where two photons enter a PBS. I hope this gives a clue to write it down.